# Storing multiple inputs in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Hello guys I still learning Java specifically arrays what I m trying to do is create sort of a mini database. I want to retrieve a name, phone number, and email address and when I call upon a name I want that information to be displayed here is what I got so far:

```
  private static  String [][] info;
  private static String name;
  private static ArrayList<String> nArray = new ArrayList<>();
  private static ArrayList<String> pArray = new ArrayList<>();
  private static ArrayList<String> eArray = new ArrayList<>();

 public static void addCustomer()
{
       Scanner new_customer = new Scanner(System.in); 

       System.out.print("Name: ");          
       name = new_customer.nextLine(); 
       nArray.add(name);

       System.out.print("Phone Number: ");
       String phone = new_customer.nextLine();
       pArray.add(phone);


       System.out.print("E-Mail Address: ");
       String email = new_customer.nextLine(); 
       eArray.add(email);                         
}     
  public static void customerInfo()
{
  int totalCustomers = nArray.size();
  System.out.print("Current Customers : "+totalCustomers+" Total\n"); 
  StringBuilder arrayOutput = new StringBuilder();
  for ( String name  : nArray) {
          arrayOutput.append(name+"\n");
  }  
    String text = arrayOutput.toString();
    System.out.print(text); 
 }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: Learn about classes... Make a `Customer` class. Store those in a `Customer[]`

Comment: @cricket_007 Exactly !

Comment: You are doing "procedural" programming. You create 3 different arrays that hold certain properties, and given any index i, the corresponding values from the arrays give you the details of a "customer". That is how you would have done this 30 years ago in a language like Pascal. In any object oriented programming language, you create classes that **model** the things in reality you deal with. And then you can put customer objects into a list ...

Comment: And please note: give your variables names that say way that they are. Like: nArray emphasizes the "array" part; which is totally irrelevant - your variable name should not express the **type** of collection you use. Instead, you would call such a thing very simple like "names". Telling you: A) it is about "names" and B) it is plural, so not a single name, but obviously some kind of thing that contains more than one name.

Comment: question simplified is how to display each customers info but yea I figured I should create a customer subclass I just wouldnt know how to call it from the superclass

Comment: Also why da hell do cocky people keep down voting everyone's gotta start somewhere

Comment: @Bob based on the new simplified question I think you will find my answer below helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you wanted to do is be able to display a particular customers info based on their name then one way you could do it is by looping through the `nArray` and comparing the values.

```
public static int getCustomerIndex(String name){
    for (int q = 0; q < nArray.size(); q++){
        if (name.equals(nArray.get(q))){
            return q;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void displayCustomer(int index){
    System.out.println("Name: " + nArray.get(index));
    System.out.println("Phone #: " + pArray.get(index));
    System.out.println("Email: " + eArray.get(index));
}
```

Bu really you will probably want to make a class `Customer` instead of having 3 different `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks  just what what i needed

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach, first create a bean class for `Customer` as below:

```
public class Customer {
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String email;

    public Customer(String name, String phone, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

And then now you can use it like this:

```
// declare list for customers
List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

// get the information from the user input
....

// create Customer
Customer customer = new Customer(name, phone, email);

// add the Customer to the list
customers.add(customer);
```

Now you have no need to declare three different `lists` for saving data

Answer (score 0):

You should program to interfaces and ensure the security of your data.
You should encapsulate what changes. You do not want references to be passed around, which could result in the changing of user info (this is unwanted). This is could result in hours of debugging. Having Getter and Setter methods for a majority of your fields defeats the purpose of OO design, description [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/10-object-oriented-design-principles.html). Not saying that you did or do, but just as a reference all who are reading and interested.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package stackexchange;

import stackexchange.user.*;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.TreeMap;

/**
 *
 * @author Tony
 */
public class StackExchange {
    private static Set<Customer> dataset;
    private static Map<String, Customer> emailQuery = null;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner istream = new Scanner(System.in);
        String in;

        dataset = new TreeSet<>(Customer.comparator);

        while (fillDatabase());

        printAll();

        while (true){
            System.out.print("Find User (y/n): ");
            in = istream.nextLine();

            // If enter null break
            if ("n".equals(in.toLowerCase()))
                break;

            System.out.print("Enter user Email: ");
            in = istream.nextLine();
            printData(findByEmail(in));
        }

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return 
     */
    private static boolean fillDatabase(){
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        UserInfo userInfo;
        String add;
        String first;
        String last;
        String phone;
        String email;

        Scanner new_customer = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.print("add user (y/n): ");          
        add = new_customer.nextLine(); 

        if ("y".equals(add.toLowerCase())){
            System.out.print("First Name: ");          
            first = new_customer.nextLine(); 

            System.out.print("Last Name: ");          
            last = new_customer.nextLine(); 

            System.out.print("Phone Number: ");
            phone = new_customer.nextLine();


            System.out.print("E-Mail Address: ");
            email = new_customer.nextLine(); 

            userInfo = new UserInfo(first, last, email, phone);
            customer.setUserInfo(userInfo);
            if (dataset.add(customer) == false){
                System.out.println("Customer : <" + first + " " + last + "> : already exists!");
            }
            return (true);
        }
        return (false);
    }

    /**
     * Get customer by id
     * @param _id [in] customer
     * @return 
     */
    private static Customer findByEmail(String _email){
        if (emailQuery == null){
            UserInfo userInfo;
            emailQuery = new TreeMap<>(); 

            for (Customer c : dataset){
                userInfo = c.getUserInfo();
                emailQuery.put(userInfo.email, c);
            }
        }

        return (emailQuery.get(_email));
    }

    /**
     * Print all data 
     */
    private static void printAll(){
        UserInfo userInfo;

        for (Customer c : dataset){
            printData(c);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Print data
     * @param _c [in] customer
     */
    private static void printData(Customer _c){
        if (_c != null){
            UserInfo userInfo = _c.getUserInfo();
            System.out.println("+==================================================+");
            System.out.println("Name: " + userInfo.firstName + " " + userInfo.lastName);
            System.out.println("Email: " + userInfo.email);
            System.out.println("Phone#: " + userInfo.phoneNumber);
            System.out.println("+==================================================+");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Error : customer cannot be null!");
        }
    }
}


/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package stackexchange.user;

/**
 * Basic user information
 * @author Tony
 */
public class UserInfo {
    public final String firstName;
    public final String lastName;
    public final String email;
    public final String phoneNumber;

    public UserInfo(String _strFirstName, String _strLastName, String _strEmail,
                String _strPhoneNumber){
        firstName   = _strFirstName;
        lastName    = _strLastName;
        email       =  _strEmail;
        phoneNumber = _strPhoneNumber;
    }

}



/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package stackexchange.user;

/**
 *
 * @author Tony
 */
public interface User {
    public static final int PRIVILEGE_ADMIN    = 0x00000001;
    public static final int PRIVILEGE_NORMAL   = 0x00000002;
    public static final int PRIVILEGE_GUEST    = 0x00000004;
    public static final int PRIVILEGE_UNKNOWN  = 0x80000000;

    /**
     * Getter Methods 
     */

    /**
     * User privileges 
     * @return 
     */
    int getPrivilege();

    /**
     * Object id 
     * @return id associated with this object 
     */
    String getObjectId();

    /**
     * User information (immutable)
     * @return instance of UserInfo 
     */
    UserInfo getUserInfo();

    /**
     * Setter Methods
     */

    /**
     * Set user information
     * @param _userInfo 
     */
    void setUserInfo(UserInfo _userInfo);

}


/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package stackexchange.user;

import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 *
 * @author Tony
 */
public class Customer implements User{
       private final String objectId;
       private final int privilegeValue;
       private String firstName;
       private String lastName;
       private String phoneNumber;
       private String email;

    public Customer(){
        objectId = this.hashCode() + "";           // Create Unique Id for each object
        privilegeValue = User.PRIVILEGE_NORMAL;    // user privileges
    }

    @Override
    public int getPrivilege() {
        return (privilegeValue);
    }

    @Override
    public String getObjectId() {
        return (objectId);
    }

    @Override
    public UserInfo getUserInfo() {
        UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber);
        return (userInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserInfo(UserInfo _userInfo) {
        if (_userInfo == null){
            System.out.println("Error : argument passed cannot be null!");
        }else{
            firstName   = _userInfo.firstName;
            lastName    = _userInfo.lastName;
            email       = _userInfo.email;
            phoneNumber = _userInfo.phoneNumber;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Compare two users
     * @param _anotherCustomer [in] user to compare with
     * @return comparison result
     */
    public int compareTo(Customer _anotherCustomer){
        return (this.objectId.compareTo(_anotherCustomer.getObjectId()));
    }

    /**
     * Used for sorting information in ADT's
     */
    public static final Comparator<Customer> comparator = new Comparator<Customer>(){
        @Override
         public int compare(Customer _c1, Customer _c2){
             return (_c1.compareTo(_c2));
         }
    };
}
```